# Cannot get Vue state's element (Vue.js/JS/TS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, npm, webpack

I met an issue today with Vue.

In a function, I cannot get an element from a state.
But when I console.log() the state, the element is there.
How to fix it?

The code:

```
export const actions: ActionTree<IState, IState> = {
    getUsers(context) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('getUsers().context=', context);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('getUsers().context.state=', context.state);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log('getUsers().context.state.baseURL=', context.state.baseURL);
      // do something...
    }
}
```

The console's log:
The 1st log is OK. I can see the value of the **baseURL**.
[image]

The 2nd log is OK too. can see the value of the **baseURL**.
[image]

The 3rd log is the problem. I cannot get the value of the **baseURL**!!!
[image]

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "2.0.0-rc",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Leo Wu <wudongyin@gmail.com>",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "^3.3.2",
    "qs": "^6.9.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "@vue/airbnb",
      "@vue/typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "max-len": "off",
      "no-param-reassign": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There probably is a race condition. In the moment the `console.log()`s are called the `baseURL` is not there yet. But when you expand the display in the console, it had enough time to load (whoever loads it had time to complete).

Comment: I would need to see the rest of your Vuex code, but normally you can inject the state (and other methods) into the action like this `getUsers({ commit, state, rootState, rootGetters }) { console.log(state.baseURL) }`

Comment: Also if it is a race condition you can wrap the method like so `getUsers(context) { this.$nextTick(() => { .console.log('getUsers().context.state.baseURL=', context.state.baseURL) }) }`

Comment: @acdcjunior, Thank you for the suggestion. But the value has been set before the code is running.

Comment: @TimWickstrom, I am sure it is not a race condition. I will try your other suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: The code that supposedly updates the value may have been triggered, but it probably hasn't been fulfilled (if it is a promise). The race condition is not in your code per se, but in it with relation to the dev tool's console. If the `$nextTick()` suggestion works, then it is a race condition (again, in relation to the console)

Comment: Hi @TimWickstrom, and acdcjunior, both of you are correct. I tried Tim's another comment, and found the value is not ready when the function called. -- So,it is a race condition. I will answer this post to give more details, and how did I fix it; just in case, someone also meets the same situation. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @acdcjunior and @TimWickstrom, 
I finally found the cause and a solution. Here are the codes comparison. The main difference is where to load the config value.

 

 **The original code (problematic)**:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');

store.commit(UPDATE_BASE_URL, {
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
});
```

**The working code:**

```
  new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  created() {
    this.$store.commit(UPDATE_BASE_URL, {
      baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
    });
  },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

S**creenshot for the working code**:
[image]

Hope it helps who meets a similar issue.